# Ford A/C issues

Tags: ford, ac

2007 Ford Explorer Limited.

When I run the A/C cold air comes out on drivers side but it comes out on the passengers side.   Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.